# New install of Ubuntu 14.04 (trusty) - 3 audio devices, no sound

Tags: sound

I'm brand new to Ubuntu. Just installed Ubuntu 14.04 (trusty) on my old Abit KN8 SLI. Everything works except sound. I went through all the troubleshooting steps here and it still doesn't work:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshooting

The sound manager shows 4 devices:

Digital Output (S/PDIF)
Analog Output / No Amplifier
Analog Output / Amplifier
HDMI / DisplayPort (Radeon HD 2350/2400 Series)

I've tried all 4 and no sound. I currently have speakers plugged into the audio jack on the back of the case, and I'm also using HDMI for video.

Sound is at 100% in the sound manager. aplay -l shows:

> **** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
>
> card 0: CK804 [NVidia CK804], device 0: Intel ICH [NVidia CK804]
>
>   Subdevices: 1/1
>
>   Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
>
> card 0: CK804 [NVidia CK804], device 2: Intel ICH - IEC958 [NVidia CK804 - IEC958]
>
>   Subdevices: 1/1
>
>   Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
>
> card 1: HDMI [HDA ATI HDMI], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
>
>   Subdevices: 1/1
>
>   Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

I don't know what to do. Please help, thanks!

Comment: If you go to "System settings" - "Sound".  Which of the four audio devices is selected???